# Best way to load properties file during runtime in mule

Tags: mule

I would like to know what would be the best way to load the properties file in mule for the following scenario.

I have a properties file where in I set all the email related fields set in it like  templates, to and from etc.
All these need to be set to a specific object along with other changes to that object so I'm planning to use a Java transformer and now I need to load all those values from that properties file and send to transformer. So what would be a best approach to work in above scenario.

1. Load properties in Java transformer using core java load properties
2. Load properties using spring context and send it to transformer and access using inbound properties

Kindly let me know if there is any other better approach other than above

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be able to load the property file using spring context as shown below:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="somename.properties" />
```

Then, you can set specific property value as flow variable as shown below:

```
<set-variable variableName="fromAddress" value="${xyz.fromAddress}" />
```

Finally, you can access this flow variable in your processor class as shown below:

```
String fromAddress = muleEvent.getFlowVariable("fromAddress");
```

Comment: Thanks Sagar for writing back... I have around 20-30 variables in that properties file in such case how do I proceed in that scenario

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use Java load properties if these properties are only used in one Transformer. There is one more benefit out of Java load properties is that after modifying your properties file you do not need to restart the application.